# How to process Multiline CSV Input File for Map Reduce Hadoop?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce, recordreader

I have CSV input data file in which there are several records. Each Record is made up of any number of lines. (1 line, 2 lines, 5 lines or any). One thing for sure is that each record has 24 fields which are separated by "::".
Each record starts on a new line but each new line is not a new record.

default record reader fails for this problem as each new line is not a new record.

**How do I take care of input splits. It may be possible for record of 3 lines, that 1 line is in one block and the other 2 are in other block?

How should I distinguish between records before they are provided as input to a map method?**

I believe it has something to do with inputformat and record-reader. Any suggestions and help is much appreciated.

Here is sample data:

review_id::text::business_id::full_address::schools::longitude::average_stars::date::user_id::open::categories::photo_url::city::review_count::name::neighborhoods::url::votes.cool::votes.funny::state::stars::latitude::type::votes.useful

NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::3.5::NaN::cxInT2YC-tuyGwKpEKAuEw::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::8::Jane A.::NaN::http://www.yelp.com/user_details?userid=cxInT2YC-tuyGwKpEKAuEw::2::1::NaN::NaN::NaN::user::5

NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::3.0::NaN::OfAuGRtKoUmwEujBoD1mfw::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::4::Amy B.::NaN::http://www.yelp.com/user_details?userid=OfAuGRtKoUmwEujBoD1mfw::1::1::NaN::NaN::NaN::user::6

fu7TcxnAOdnbdLcyFhMmZg::Pretty great!  Okay, so this place is obviously not Vegan since they have a bunch of cheese and egg offerings, BUT I see that they do offer plenty of vegan alternatives.

I was sort of skeptical being here because the prices were pretty hefty, I felt.
Anyway, their homemade hot sauce is AMAZING.  I got the eggs benedict for dinner and J got an omelet.  Both were really good.  I do love their homefries.. but the next time I come here, I want onion rings or fries.  Those onion rings looked amazing.

Lastly, the food came relatively quickly.

Not a fan of the service.  They tried to seat us at this edge facing the stoves, without asking, so I asked for a booth.  Then at the booth, the server didn't refill waters very well but didn't feel bad emphasizing over and over whether or not we wanted their $5-7 desserts.  Honestly, a slice of pie for $6.50?  Veggie Galaxy, you are t r i p p i n !

But great food! (especially breaky!)::qw5gR8vW7mSOK4VROSwdMA::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::2011-11-12::Z_WAxc4RUpKp3y12BH1bEg::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::0::1::NaN::4::NaN::review::0

85TbS2RT5f6kqZ5l7_jfRw::Great place!

I have to say the menu and the outdoor seating keep us coming back.  The food is good -- had breakfast both times but some friends had lunch items. Definitely a great selection.  We've been at off-peak times so no waiting and better service.

All in all, it's no DZ Akins but it's definitely worth trying!::-tphABJRkegXV4Fr1ke4FQ::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::2010-09-19::1IzWxAfxuHTnzKOupUOB5Q::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::NaN::0::0::NaN::4::NaN::review::0

Comment: Can you copy/paste an CSV example?

Comment: I have added few records from the data set in the above description.

Comment: I think such file cannot be split into multiple input splits as there is no way to determine the beginning of each record.You can override isSplittable method not to split the file and have a recordreader implementation that generates key-value pairs based on number of '::' parsed.

Comment: thank you ! do you have any sample code or any reference that I can go through?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a custom input format, returning complete records instead of single lines.